# Bash conditional execution

Tags: bash

I took this code from a script I found online :

```
[ $# = 0 ] && usage
```

If there are no parameters at the command line, then call the `usage` method (which print the help info).

The thing I don't understand is why does the script exits after calling usage? Shouldn't it simply continue to other code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways this can happen:

1. The `usage` method has an `exit` command in it
2. The `usage` method has a `return 1` command (or other non-zero value) and the script is invoked with `-e` flag, for example `#!/bin/sh -e` shebang
3. The `usage` method has an operation that fails and the script is invoked with `-e` flag

Maybe there are more ways that I don't recall now.

Personally, I always use `exit 1` as the last command in a `usage` method, so the behavior seems all natural to me.

Answer (score 2):

It would carry on unless 'usage' executes 'exit' command